# Typescript - Sort an array based on another array properties integer value

Tags: angular, sorting, arraylist, iteration

I have a two array list and I want sorted second ArrayList using first array position values:
1.

```
position = [
   {
      "id":25,
      "name":"Hungry Test",
      "description":"Whats for dinner?",
      "rev":1,
      "fields":[
         {
            "position":2,
            "name":"Veg",
            "type":"STRING"
         },
         {
            "position":1,
            "name":"Meat",
            "type":"STRING"
         },
         {
            "position":3,
            "name":"Bread",
            "type":"STRING"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":28,
      "name":"Hungry Test",
      "description":"Whats for dinner?",
      "rev":1,
      "fields":[
         {
            "position":2,
            "name":"Veg",
            "type":"STRING"
         },
         {
            "position":1,
            "name":"Meat",
            "type":"STRING"
         },
         {
            "position":3,
            "name":"Bread",
            "type":"STRING"
         }
      ]
   }
      ]
   }
]
```

2.

```
    data_points =
    [ {
      "job" : 155,
      "name" : "One Activity",
      "status" : "STARTED",
      "data_points" : [ {
        "user_id" : 11,
        "rev" : 1,
        "device_id" : "7",
        "Bread" : "Yes",
        "Meat" : "Fish",
        "Veg" : "Mushroom"
      } ]
    }, {
      "job" : 155,
      "name" : "Two Activity",
      "status" : "STARTED",
      "data_points" : [ {
        "user_id" : 11,
        "rev" : 1,
        "device_id" : "7",
        "Bread" : "No",
        "Meat" : "Prawns",
        "Veg" : "Malai Kofta"
      } ]
    }]
    } ]
```

so that the order corresponds to the first array "position" value.
This would be the output expected: only for 3 properties Meat, Veg, and Bread

```
    "data_points" : [ {
        "user_id" : 11,
        "rev" : 1,
        "device_id" : "7",
        **"Meat" : "Fish",   //position = 1
        "Veg" : "Mushroom"   //position = 2
        "Bread" : "Yes",**   //position = 3
      } ]
```

please help me to sort this ArrayList using position values.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are **not** trying to sort an array, but trying to change the order of `keys` in an object?

Comment: yes! you are right

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: It requirement so.

Comment: @Rahul Objects are an unordered collection of properties, therefore you can not order the properties as you want. You need an array. You could transform those 3 properties to something like `"food": [{"Meat": "Fish"}, {"Veg": "Mushroom"}, {"Bread": "Yes"}]`